# Save dynamic variables on page close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, cookies

I'm currently building a website for a school project that loads json data into the page dynamically as the user navigates. Here's the code I'm working with right now:

```
$(function () {  
var $divs = $(".divs > div"),
    N = $divs.length,
    C = 0;                   // Current    

$divs.hide().eq(C).show();
$("#next, #prev").click(function () {
    $divs.stop().fadeOut().eq((this.id == 'next' ? ++C : --C) %N).fadeIn();       
}); // close click function
}); // close main function

var content = jSONtexts.texts;
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#content0").html(content[0].content);
$("#content1").html(content[1].content);
$("#content2").html(content[2].content);
$("#content3").html(content[3].content);
$("#content4").html(content[4].content);
$("#content5").html(content[5].content);
$("#content6").html(content[6].content);
$("#content7").html(content[7].content);
$("#content8").html(content[8].content);
});
```

In my html I have divs set up as containers for the particular json data that I want to be presented. It's rudimentary right now, but the user clicks 'next' or 'previous' and a different section of the json loads into the visible div.

What I need is to be able to save what div is showing (maybe using the 'C' variable?) - into a cookie, and load that div when the user returns. I've tried using js.cookie.js, and it's quite possible that I'm using it wrong, Here's what I'm trying:

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
    Cookies.set('pageState', 'C');
 }); //close cookie function
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. It breaks my json loading when I try to put it anywhere in the .js file that would be relevant to the C variable.

I'm stumped. I've looked everywhere on google, and everything that people are saying to try breaks my json function. Help please!

If someone has any ideas I would be eternally grateful!

Thanks
Sam

Comment: you can use `localStorage` http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: You could try using just the standard cookie functionality: `document.cookie = 'yourCookieText';` and `allCookies = document.cookie;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie is not a best practice to save these data, as cookies will be send with all requests.

> Use need to use HTML5 `localStorage` to save data at client side.
>   http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Made demo for the same

```js
document.getElementById("textInput").value = localStorage.getItem("pageState");

window.addEventListener("unload", function() {
   localStorage.setItem("pageState", document.getElementById("textInput").value);
 });
```

```html
<input id="textInput" type="text" />
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/vvkdge2q/

Comment: This seems to be the way I need to go - Thanks! 

Can I set the .getElementById to be the 'C' variable in my code? I need it to change dynamically as the user interacts with the page. 

Would I need to set an intermediary variable to transfer the value?

Answer (score 0):

as @KishoreSahas already suggested in the comments, I would suggest you to use `localStorage` instead of cookies.

You could store what you need like this

```
localStorage.setItem("veryimportantdata", "INeedThisLater");
```

and get it back later like this

```
var data = localStorage.getItem("veryimportantdata");
console.log(data); // prints out "INeedThisLater"
```